# Query errors in a panda Dataframe

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pandas

I am facing an issue with my code using queries on simple pandas DataFrame, I am sure I am missing a tiny detail. Can you guys help me with this?
[image]

I don't understand why I've only NAN values.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `[['date']]` to `[date]` for select `Series` instead one column `DataFrame`.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})

print (df['A'])
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

print (df[['A']])
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

print (df[df['A'] == 1])
   A
0  1

print (df[df[['A']] == 1])
     A
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  NaN
```